# How can I select a radio button that has a value starts with a number in iMacros?

Tags: imacros

I've a group of radio buttons in a web page.

Some of them has a value starts with special characters (for no specific reason).

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="$12345"/>
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="#12345"/>
```

Some of them has a value starts with numbers.

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="12345"/>
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="67890"/>
```

I want to select any one of them which has a value starts with a number. And this is my iMacros:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=NAME:form1 CONTENT=%{1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0}*
```

I read the documentation and couldn't find what I'm looking for!

Comment: use regular experssion

Comment: You have to use javascript scripting. Extract the HTML code of the wanted input HTML tag. Then get the value and insert in iMacros code.

Comment: Can't this be done using native iMacros syntax? Because, I'm running Chrome and it doesn't support .js files.